# C# unit test replace method in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Lets say I have constructor like this

```
        internal Func<...> MyFunc { get; set; }
        public SomeClass(ISomeParam param)
                : base(param)
            {
                MyFunc = MyMethod;
                MyPropertyX = MyFunc(someOtherParams);
            }
```

How can I change that Func in tests? So constructor is called with mocked different func from test. I tried something like this but does not work.

```
    var SubjectUnderTest = new MyClass(params) {
        MyFunc = MyNewMethodInsteadOfThatOneInClass
    };
```

Comment: The easy solution is to make it visible to the tests. Otherwise you'd have to use Reflection to find the property and assign a value to it, a complicated job that makes the test itself fragile. Apart from the code's complexity, changes in the `Func<...>` signature wouldn't be noticed at compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Func is a dependency of the class, it might make sense to extract it into a separate class and inject a different implementation via constructor:

```
public SomeClass(ISomeParam param, ISomeFunc func)
                : base(param)
{
    this.func = func;
    MyPropertyX = func.MyFuncImpl(someOtherParams);
}
```

```
public interface ISomeFunc
{
    public object MyFuncImpl(object someOtherParams);

}
```

```
public class SomeFuncImpl : ISomeFunc
{
    public object MyFuncImpl(object someOtherParams)
    {
        // whatever your Func<...> MyFunc does
    }
}

public class TestFuncImpl : ISomeFunc
{
    public object MyFuncImpl(object someOtherParams)
    {
        return true; // or whatever
    }

}
```

In your test you can then pass a different implementation:

```
var testImpl = new TestFuncImpl();
var SubjectUnderTest = new MyClass(params, testImpl);
```

Comment: I did it differently there was a way to mock something inside at the end of the day its ugly but working. Anyway need to accept some answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without diving into details of the design, the option would be to make the internals visible to the test project via `InternalsVisibleTo` for example by adding the following to the tested project .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <InternalsVisibleTo Include ="YourTestProjectAssemblyName"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that you still will need to call `MyPropertyX = MyFunc(someOtherParams);` too because object initializers are invoked after constructor, so maybe you just need to refactor `SomeClass` constructor to accept an optional `MyFunc` parameter (or add another ctor):

```
public SomeClass(ISomeParam param, Func<...> func) : base(param)
{
    MyFunc = func;
    MyPropertyX = func.MyFuncImpl(someOtherParams);
}
```

Comment: An ugly alternative is to use reflection, but apart from code complexity it would miss changes to the Func signature until runtime